# Can we convert a freestyle job in jenkins into a template

Tags: templates, jenkins

I have configured a freestyle Jenkins job to perform build, run some tests, perform code analysis and upload artifacts to Nexus. I will need to create more of such jobs in future and so I want to create a template so that its easy for anyone else to create those jobs in future. Is there a way to convert the freestyle job into template?

Answer (score 0):

You can create generic mechanisms using Ant(In my case NAnt), and use them using a set of imported variables.
My config for web app looks like:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <webapps>
      <add basedir="deploys\JobLocation" deploydir="C:\CIReference\Sites" appname="JobLocation" appid="5" appuri="http/*:8081" apppool.runtineversion="v4.0" />
    </webapps>
```

> The add tag has the basic configuration of the webapp

And the generic mechanism to deploy web application is like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="webdeploy" xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.92/nant.xsd">
  <include buildfile="baseconfigs.xml" />
  <include buildfile="external_tools.xml" />
  <call target="baseConfigs" />
  <property name="current.environment.path" value="${path::combine(nant.environmentsdir,environment)}"/>
  
  <foreachxml file="${path::combine(current.environment.path,'webapps.xml')}" xpath="/webapps/add" property="basedir,deploydir,appname,appid,appuri,apppool.runtineversion">
    <exec program="${appcmd.path}" failonerror="false">
      <arg value="delete" />
      <arg value="site" />
      <arg value="/site.name: ${appname}" />
    </exec>

    <exec program="${appcmd.path}" failonerror="false">
      <arg value="delete" />
      <arg value="apppool" />
      <arg value="/apppool.name: ${appname}" />
    </exec>

    <echo message="Deleting directory: ${path::combine(deploydir, appname)}" />
    <delete dir="${path::combine(deploydir, appname)}" failonerror="false" />

    <echo message="Coping directory to: ${path::combine(deploydir, appname)}" />
    <copy todir="${path::combine(deploydir, appname)}" includeemptydirs="true" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
      <fileset basedir="${path::combine(directory::get-current-directory(), basedir)}">
        <include name="**\*.*" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    
    <exec program="${appcmd.path}">
      <arg value="add" />
      <arg value="apppool" />
      <arg value="/name: ${appname}" />
    </exec>
    <exec program="${appcmd.path}">
      <arg value="set" />
      <arg value="apppool" />
      <arg value="/name: ${appname}" />
      <arg value="/managedRuntimeVersion:${apppool.runtineversion}" />
    </exec>
    <exec program="${appcmd.path}">
      <arg value="add" />
      <arg value="site" />
      <arg value="/name: ${appname}" />
      <arg value="/id: ${appid}" />
      <arg value="/bindings: ${appuri}" />
      <arg value="/physicalPath: ${path::combine(deploydir, appname)}" />
    </exec>

    <exec program="${appcmd.path}" failonerror="false">
      <arg value="set" />
      <arg value="site" />
      <arg value="${appname}" />
      <arg value="/applicationPool:${appname}" />
    </exec>

  </foreachxml>

</project>
```

You can use this tool to create whatever mechanism do you need for your CI solution.

Order files...

> baseconfigs.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
  
  <property name="nant.dir" value="" />
  <property name="nant.environmentsdir" value="" />
  <target name="baseConfigs">
    <cd dir="..\..\" />
    <property name="nant.dir" value="${path::combine(directory::get-current-directory(),'jenkins\NAnt')}" />
    <property name="nant.environmentsdir" value="${path::combine(nant.dir,'environments')}" />
  </target>
  
</project>
```

> external_tools.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
  <property name="appcmd.path" value="c:\windows\System32\InetSrv\appcmd.exe" />
  <property name="java_path" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin"/>
  <property name="liquibase_exe_path" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\liquibase\"/>
  <loadtasks assembly="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\nant\nantcontrib\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
  <loadtasks assembly="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\nant\NAnt.GF.Custom.Tasks.dll" />

  
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Leonardo, Thanks for your reply. I am still interested in creating templates in Jenkins to perform my work. While your comment provides a solution to the task I have to perform, but for a large enterprise, I think its not a proper solution and I  would still like to use templates.